# Scanner which will recognize only CR LF

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am reading a file using the scanner class.I want my EOL delimiter to be CR LF but there are some records in the file which have only LF hence my scanner is reading the LF and going to the next line. I want the scanner to go to the next line only when it encounters CR LF both.
Here is my snippet: (using double slashes in the regex also gives same result)

```
java.util.Scanner sMain = new java.util.Scanner(inputStream,encoding)
                              .useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("[\r\n]"));
while (sMain.hasNextLine()) {  
// sysout line  
}
```

Comment: If you are on a Windows machine you could try to use System.getProperty("line.separator") for your Pattern. Don't know if that helps as I can't try it out right now.

Comment: yes i am aware that this will work but i am using scanner and my code is revolved around it so i wouldnt wanna change it.

Comment: Have you tried it like this: Pattern.compile("(\r\n)"); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want a delimiter which is

```
"\r\n"
```

`"[\r\n]"` means one of \r or \n.

The delimiter determines the separator between "words". To break up the line you can use split("~") as follows.

```
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream((
        "a line~with a \r and~a \n in it \r\n" +
        "a line with \n\r in~it\r\n").getBytes());

Scanner sMain = new Scanner(inputStream,"UTF-8").useDelimiter("\r\n");
Pattern wordPattern = Pattern.compile("~");
while (sMain.hasNext()) {
    String line = sMain.next();
    line = line.replaceAll("\r", "\\\\r").replaceAll("\n", "\\\\n");
    String[] words = wordPattern.split(line);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(words));
}
```

prints

```
[a line, with a \r and, a \n in it ]
[a line with \n\r in, it]
```

Comment: i want both. i guess \r is for CR and \n is for LF right ? I want the scanner to go to the next line if it gets both \r and \n

Comment: So you want `\r` followed by `\n` which means you want `\r\n`

Comment: yes but as i have written useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("[\r\n]")) does not give me the desired result. My scanner still goes to the next line when it gets only an LF

Comment: Which is is why I told you to use `\r\n` and explained why `[\r\n]` wouldn't work.

Comment: The problem is that the delimiter is the separator between "words"

Comment: The seperator between the words here is ~ and not \r\n

Comment: So you have to use `~` as your delimiter.

Comment: AFAIK, you can only specify one delimiter.  The new line delimiter is hard coded as `\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085]` I suggest you break up the stream by lines using the approach above and then break up each line by words.

Comment: wait i think im confused now.I am using line.split(fileSeperator) to split my records but i was setting the scanner.useDelimiter to know when to split a line. My records have ~ as a seperator but my EOL should only be CRLF. No where in my line do i encounter a \r or \n except at the end

Comment: In that case you can use "~" as your delimiter and you don't need to change you line separator.

Comment: using ~ as my delimiter in scanner.useDelimiter still splits a line when it encounters a single LF .

Comment: You don't need to worry about that because `No where in my line do i encounter a \r or \n except at the end` \n is LF.

Comment: ok sorry let me reprhase: one line has LF in it. And even after using the replaceAll function you provided the scanner still splits the record at LF. And i am printing everything within the scanner itself so i am sure that im not making a mistake while reading it

Comment: The replaceAll is for printing purposes.  If you can have a LF in a line you have to use the solution I suggested. It shows that LF is handled as expected.

Comment: i am so sorry . I gt i to work now . The mistake i was making was i was using scanner.nextLine() instead of scaneer.next() as u suggested. Thanx a ton

Comment: hi i am facing an error while reading a huge file with 50 columns. I am getting java heap space error at: line= sMain.next(). How i can solve this ?

Comment: Increase the memory available, and/or process the file as you get it so you are not storing as much in memory.  You can also ensure `-XX:+UseCompressedStrings` is enabled. BTW: Here is an example of loading a huge 8 TB file. http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-memory-mapped-file-for-huge.html  "Huge" can mean just about anything. ;)

Comment: ur blog looks really impressive but went over my head :( . I am stil new at java . U mentioned i can process the file as i get it .. How can i do that in the code u mentioned above ?I was of the opinion that i was reading every token till i encounter the delimiter.

Comment: I assume you have enough memory to read a whole line at a time.  You can then do what ever you are going to do with that line before reading and processing the next.  This could be an alternative to reading all the lines into a collection and then processing the data.

Comment: while (sMain.hasNext()) {  String line = sMain.next();  } i am getting an error at line = sMain.next() itself. So i presume i am unable to read the line . Isn't it ? Here if i had sMain.nextLine() , i can store it in line . Is there a workaround here ?

Comment: `while (sMain.hasNext()) { String line = sMain.next(); } ` won't get an OutOfMemoryError unless you are trying to read a single line of text is larger than the memory you have.  Either you have more code than this which is the actual cause of memory being consumed or you text format needs to change so you don't have such long lines.

Comment: yes thanx again peter. But here for useDelimiter, we are hardcoding \r\n. What if its a linux file ? the seperator will be \n . So how can i know which OS a file is generated from ? Is there something in java for this ?

Comment: You have to be able to say how you would tell the difference between a `\n` which is in the middle of a line and a `\n` which is the line.  If you can't tell the difference, how would you expect Java to do so? (I am not saying its impossible, but you need to collect more information to be able to tell the difference)

Comment: ok so is there a way in java to find out which OS a file has originated from ? i mean if i open a file in notepad ++ it shows me the OS of the file. So is there some way in java as well ?

Comment: You can count the number of `\r\n` or `\n` alone or `\r` alone in the file and assume that the most common indicates the source. You can't tell (without additional information) if `\n` is the end of a line or in the middle of line.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are printing it after scanning. The problem isn't with Regex. Peter is right:
Following is correct:

```
"\r\n"
```

But remember, if you print, a single \n  or \r is still considered as newline. So it may appear as more lines. Following test code clarifies it:

```
public class ScannerTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner("I am first \r\n I am second \n Am I? \r Really?");
   sc.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("\r\n"));
   int count=0;
   while (sc.hasNext()) {
          count++;
          System.out.println(sc.next());      
   }

   System.out.println("Total No of Lines:"+count);

   }

}
```

Notice the no. of lines read by scanner is 2.

Comment: yes i get wat u r trying to say but the scanner is still splitting for me when i encounter a LR

Answer (score 0):

Try `(\r\n|\r|\n)`, the regex engine default try to match the first option first.

Comment: This doesnt work for me . This again is going to the next line whenever i encounter an LF . I want it to go to the next line only if i encounter LF CR